# How to use DefineComponent() with Composition API in Vue, when components have the same methods?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use a plugin `VueDraggableNext` in a  project that also used `Vuetify`. Both plugins have a `<draggable>` element.
If I use the 'Options' API with Vue, I can use the following method to define which version of `<draggable>` I want to use:

```
<script>
  ....
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
  import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next'
  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      draggable: VueDraggableNext,
    },
   ....
   ....
```

and it works. But I wish to use the Composition API (it's what I'm used to!) - what is the syntax for `defineComponent()` in this case? I have tried re-ordering the imports, but to no effect, the `vuetify` version of `<draggable>` is always used.

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { VueDraggableNext }  from'vue-draggable-next'
// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
import '../assets/main.css'
createApp(App).use(vuetify).use(VueDraggableNext).mount('#app')
```

and I have tried the following in my `vue.js` but get error 'components is not defined'.

```
<script setup>

import { reactive,components} from 'vue'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { VueDraggableNext }  from'vue-draggable-next'
defineComponent(
  components = {
    draggable: VueDraggableNext }
)
....
....
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by " Components API" and "and I have tried this in vue.js". The second snippet is called "script setup", that's the term. It should be `import { VueDraggableNext as Draggable }  from'vue-draggable-next'`. Is this what you asked about

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed, I meant Composition API not Componets API. Anyway, your note has fixed it - `import { VueDraggableNext as draggable}  from'vue-draggable-next'` is what's required. Thank you!